# How to check value from other sharepoint list?

Tags: list, workflow, caml

I have two custom lists in SharePoint 2010 (Absent Request and Employee Leave Balance) with these columns:

**Absent Request List:** Absent Type, Approver, Start Date, End Date, Absent Reason

**Employee Leave Entitlement:** Employee Name, Approver, Annual Leave Balance, Sick Leave Balance, Hospitalize Leave Balance, etc.

When John creates an absent request for 5 days Annual Leave in Absent Request List, a workflow will check John's leave balance from the Employee Leave Balance List (under the Annual Leave column) to see whether John is still entitled to take 5 days annual leave.

Is it possible to use a CAML query to do this check?